# How can I aggregate all build artifacts from a Hudson multiplatform matrix build?

Tags: hudson

We have a Hudson nightly matrix build that produces quite a few build artifacts (for several different platforms and oracle versions). I would like to create a downstream Hudson job that gets all the successful build artifacts from our nightly build and then does something with them.

Is there an easy way to do this?

I've looked at the ability to scp the build artifacts somewhere after a build, but we'd rather not have to introduce some sort of temporary holding directory for builds. It seems more elegant to be able to get them directly from the Hudson when the downstream job gets started.

Right now I'm contemplating a little python script to parse the nightly build's html and find the links to all the artifacts (they're all of the form: "http://hudson:8080/trunk/750/ab.oracle.version=10.2.0,label=linux/artifact/artifact.zip"). We add and remove platforms regularly. I think the python script will work, but it's such a hack!

Comment: At least use one of the APIs rather than scraping the HTML. https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Copy Artifact plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) is able to collect artifacts from a matrix build and consolidate them in a single workspace. It can be configured to copy from certain axes/configurations or alternatively *all* configurations.

Comment: Great! This seems to solve my problem perfectly. Although, I asked this question a year and a half ago, so we have since written the hacky python script, :). Will use the plugin going forward though. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We used a common network share to hold all of our artifacts.

It would be nice if Hudson contain a repository, but given that the core development team uses Maven, which provides those kinds of features, it may be a while.